# Difference Between Keras Backend Calls

Tags: tensorflow, keras, backend

What is the difference between

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
```

and

```
from keras import backend as K
```

Why when I use the first does the model run faster, but give incorrect results?

Comment: Different versions of the software. tensorflow seems to have been reimplementing Keras in 1.4 and 2.0 branches. bottom line: do not mix and match. Either import always ```tensorflow.keras.<module>``` or always ```keras.<module>```. If you are using TF you probably want to do ```from tensorflow import keras```.

Comment: Importing from tensorflow always gives wrong results though. What if I'm using Tensorflow 1.8 with Keras 2.1.6?